# Dojo Parser - Parsing completed?

Tags: parsing, dojo

Is there a way to find whether dojo has completed parsing when `dojo.parse.parser(dom-id)` was invoked to parse the document?

I don't want to rely on `dojo.addOnLoad()` as I am invoking parser on my own.

Answer (score 3):

It's done a bit differently in Dojo 1.8:

> ... Dojo 1.8 can cause the parser to run in an asynchronous fashion ...

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/_base/array"], function(parser, array){
  parser.parse().then(function(instances){
    array.forEach(instances, function(instance){
      // do something with instances
    });
  });
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/parser.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that invoking `dojo.parser.parse` is a synchronous call, meaning that the next line will only execute once that function has finished parsing widgets.  Is there any particular reason to believe that code after `dojo.parser.parse(node)` is executing before the widgets in the dom are created?

Using the `parseOnLoad: true` property is another story though, which I don't believe is applicable in your case.

Comment: You are right. My Javascript logic was scattered in the HTML file. Once I made changes to invoke it after dojo.parser.parse(), it worked. Thanks for your reply.